# Shared_Ptr eates the performance of my application

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr

I'm on Ubuntu, and I'm working on a computer vision application (optical flow), and I'm doing some profiling on the code using valgrind. 
After profiling, I found that the shared_ptr is taking 74% of the application. Kindly find the attached code that where the shared_ptr is used. I'm looking for an optimization for that. Besides that, also sprintf takes so much time, and the openMP threads also eats a lot. I'm really wondering about sprinft, and openMP cost...

```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //QApplication a(argc, argv);


    omp_set_dynamic( 0 );
    omp_set_num_threads( 4 );

    double t1, t2;

    // ------------- Initialization: Frames. --------------

    // Load first image
    char imFName[1024];
    sprintf( imFName, "%s/img_%08i.png", imPath.c_str(), imIndex );
    ifstream fileExists( imFName );

    if (!fileExists)
    {
        printf("First image %s/img_%08i.png could not be loaded!", imPath.c_str(), imIndex);
        return -1;
    }

    QImagePtr prevImg;
    QImagePtr curImg( new QImage( QString(imFName) ) );



}
```

Comment: This is not enough information for us to do anything.  What does `ZtAbsoluteSystemItem` do for example?

Comment: To understand whether shared_ptr is the problem, compare profiling results with native pointer and unique_ptr.

Comment: @TonyTheLion just initializes camera paramters.

Comment: Show the actual profiler log.

Comment: @n.m. I added profiler image, and full code

Comment: Are you profiling a debug build? The results could be skewed. Try release.

Comment: @n.m it's a release build using valgrind on a cross compiled platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that `shared_ptr` is the culprit, but the `new` and `delete`.

You allocate memory on the heap, assign it to `item` and when the scope of the for loop ends, it frees it. So you have an expensive noop.

As @nvoigt already suggested, use an automatic object

```
CharachterDetection item(frame);
```

and change the accesses from `item->` to `item.`.

In your picture, the location is `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/...`. If this is not a native run, but on a simulated virtual machine, I wouldn't rely on any results.

**Update**:

You run sprintf in a loop and repeatedly copy the path and afterwards put it in a QString again. Maybe using one of [`QString::arg`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#arg) is better suited. But this is just a guess.

Comment: so what should I do to solve that issue? just allocate on the stack ?

Comment: @Mahmoud Yes, if your object isn't too large, this would be the correct fix.

Comment: Do you have an idea also why sprintf takes alot of time ?

Comment: it is a cross compiled version using QT

Comment: @Mahmoud Does it run on the target hardware?

Comment: I have found a problem, that functions use that shared_ptr, and that shared_ptr has been passed to a lot of functions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are missing some code in your post? Your shared pointer doesn't seem to do anything but construct and delete your object. If the constructor code of said object is needed, you could just put the object on the stack:

```
// ----------------------- Perform Marker Detection ------------------------
ZtAbsoluteSystemItem item(frame);
```

Comment: I'm still not clear about why you are using shared_ptr instead of putting the object on the stack. Is it too large for the stack, or did I miss a part of the code where you insert it into some container spanning the loops lifetime?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code where exactly the problem is, so I can only offer two general pieces of advice I found useful in the past:

- Avoid using `new` manually, look into [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) to make allocations more efficient.
- Avoid useless reference counting. When taking a parameter that is a `std::shared_ptr`, take it as `const std::shared_ptr<...>&` instead of creating a copy of the `std::shared_ptr` which implies an atomic increment and decrement per function call.